# How do i prevent entering in input any character except letters and one underscore in a row?

Tags: javascript, html, regex, input, preventdefault

I can't create an input in which the first character entered must be a letter, and the following characters can be only letters or only one underscore in a row

i have an input and following javascript code for it:

```
var nick = document.getElementById('donate-nickname');

function validatenick(evt) {
    var regex = /^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z_]*$/;
    if(!regex.test(nick.value)) evt.preventDefault();
}

nick.onkeydown = validatenick;
nick.onpaste = validatenick;
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: `/^[A-Za-z]+(?:_[A-Za-z]+)*$/`?

Comment: unfortunately, i can still enter any character

Comment: Maybe this works too: [`/^[a-z]+_?[a-z]*$/i`](https://regex101.com/r/lhVTPk/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some issues:

- You are not assigning `visited` to `onkeydown`, but instead execute it. (You fixed this after I posted this answer)
- `input.value` will reflect the input as it is **before** the key was processed, so the validation check comes too early.
- The regex does not implement the logic you describe

I would suggest a regex where you perform a negative look-ahead for a double underscore. Also make it allow empty input as else the user cannot delete the last character that remains in the input.

For responding to all input methods, use the `input` event. Then to cancel the edit that would break the pattern, you could keep track of the most recent input that was still valid, and when there is a violation of the pattern, roll back to that value:

```js
var input = document.getElementById('nickname');

var lastValid = "";

function validate(evt) {
    var regex = /^(?!_)(?!.*?__)[A-Za-z_]*$/;
    if(!regex.test(input.value)) {
        input.value = lastValid;
    }
    lastValid = input.value;
}

input.oninput = validate;
```

```html
<input id="nickname">
```

As a side note, I would personally not block edits like that: users may wrongly think their keyboard is malfunctioning. It is better practice to let the user type what they want, but accompany it with feedback (coloring, an error message, ...).